# Tags results not displaying for post types

Tags: custom-post-types, template-tags

**UPDATE**

Here is the thing...

I have a structure where I created a post type which has taxonomies and also tags. Let's call it **Works.**

However, when I need to filter by tags, using the tag template, it displays only the blog post posts taged with the blog tags, and do not display the tags used on the post type.

**Works has Taxonomies** like: In-house, OutSourced. (there is no problem with taxonomies, just displaying this just in case...)

**Works has tags** like: Iron, Wood, etc.

So... According to my main guess, if I want to display a filter by tags, or just clicking a tag link generated. I have to create the `tag.php` template, and into the loop, I will have all works tagged with a particular tag.

However... the result is empty, or worst... I have a similar tag but into the BLOG section, it will display the blog post, which actually, is normal behavior.

I tried going a level deep and used the `archive.php` template instead, however it does not show it either, same thing as `tag.php`.

So... the point is, if I want to create a filter that display my custom post type, `Works`, tagged with a particular tag, which is the template I need to create?

If I get I click the tag generated, it actually takes me to `example.com/tag/my-tag`, which is in fact, the problem (I think), cause that is the root for blog posts.

Any guessing?

Comment: Your question/problem is hard to follow. Can you please try to clean this up and clarify it?

Comment: Sure... I will update